# Acoustic Guitar - how do I connect a Boss Looper pedal with a Zoom AC3 and a Fishman Amp

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I'm wondering how I would go about hooking up a Boss RC-3 looper with my Fishman Amp and a Zoom AC3.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simple is gtr>Zoom>Boss>Amp. All with jack to jack. I guess the gtr has a pup. If not, you'll need a mic too.